# How to filter ios push notifications before they appear

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, push-notification

Is there anyway to filter push notifications that im send to my app?

I mean, if my user logged out (fb connect) from my app and for somereason my server is miss sync with the loggin-out, i will send to the user notifications while he logged out, which is unwanted situation..

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do your filtering server-side. There is nothing your app can do on a device to filter its incoming notifications. Your app may not be running when the notification occurs, and may not be launched if the user disregards the notification.

Answer (score 0):

You can set BOOL variable to false on log-out. so whenever Notification arrive, you check BOOL value, if false don't process Notification and if true do whatever you want to do.
this is just an example case, you can use same logic anywhere else to process Notifications.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`unregisterForRemoteNotifications`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1623093-unregisterforremotenotifications?language=objc) method.